# is GetLocaleInfo with LOCALE_SABBREVLANGNAME deprecated?

Tags: windows, winapi, localization, locale, globalization

When I do `GetLocaleInfo($0C51, LOCALE_SABBREVLANGNAME, Language, LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH);` it's return **ZZZ**. ZZZ seam to be an invalid code for Dzonghka language (bhutan). Does it's mean that GetLocaleInfo / LOCALE_SABBREVLANGNAME is deprecated ?

Comment: Are you checking the return value of `GetLocaleInfo()` to make sure the contents of your `Language` buffer are valid once `GetLocaleInfo()` exits? Are you zeroing out your `Language` buffer before passing it to `GetLocaleInfo()`?

Comment: Legacy LCIDs are discouraged. Update to using [named locales](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/locale-names) with `GetLocaleInforEx`. The `LOCALE_SNAME` uses the ISO 639 (`LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME`) and ISO-3166 (`LOCALE_SISO3166CTRYNAME`) codes.

Comment: @ErykSun the problem is that i already store old name in database and LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME / LOCALE_SISO3166CTRYNAME produce different alpha 3 code than LOCALE_SABBREVLANGNAME :(

Comment: Try checking all locales for additional "ZZZ.ZZZ" abbreviated names via `EnumSystemLocalesEx`. I'd guess that Microsoft isn't updating the deprecated `SABBREVLANGNAME` and `SABBREVCTRYNAME` fields for newly added locales. They've supported standard ISO codes since at least NT 4.0 in 1996.

Comment: Migrate the database to ISO standard names if you can.

Comment: @ErykSun it's not so easy especially if the alpha 2 code is exchanged with other entities :( but yes 15 years ago would be good if i used iso instead of LOCALE_SABBREVLANGNAME   :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I can reproduce this issue. `GetLocaleInfo` return 4 and Language is `L"ZZZ"`.

Then, As Document [`GetLocaleInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getlocaleinfoa) said,

> For interoperability reasons, the application should prefer the
>   [`GetLocaleInfoEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getlocaleinfoex) function to `GetLocaleInfo` because Microsoft is
>   migrating toward the use of locale names instead of locale identifiers
>   for new locales. Any application that runs only on Windows Vista and
>   later should use `GetLocaleInfoEx`.

As @Eryk pointed out, and which is also metioned in the [WinNls.h](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.16299.0/um/WinNls.h#L750):

```
#define LOCALE_SABBREVLANGNAME        0x00000003   // DEPRECATED arbitrary abbreviated language name, LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME instead.
```

In addition, ISO 639-1 and ISO 639-2:

```
#define LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME        0x00000059   // ISO abbreviated language name, eg "en"
...
#define LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME2       0x00000067   // 3 character ISO abbreviated language name, eg "eng"
```

If you want to get a "3 character ISO abbreviated language name", sample:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int ret = 0;
    //wchar_t name[LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH] = { 0 };
    //LCID LocaleID = 0x0c51;
    //ret = LCIDToLocaleName(LocaleID, name, LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH, LOCALE_ALLOW_NEUTRAL_NAMES);
    //wprintf(L"%s\n", name);//dz-BT

    wchar_t name[] = L"dz-BT";
    wchar_t Language[LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH] = { 0 };

    ret = GetLocaleInfoEx(name, LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME2, Language, LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH);
    wprintf(L"%s\n", Language);//dzo
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes but LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME2 is not the same as LOCALE_SABBREVLANGNAME, especially if we saved the old language code in database :(